# DJANGO get objects in sql like join

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

**Context: I'm forcing my self to learn django, I already wrote a small php based website, so I'm basically porting over the pages and functions to learn how django works.**

I have 2 models

```
from django.db import models

class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Combo(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dead = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    siteID = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('username','siteID')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}:{self.password}@{self.siteID.name}"
```

When creating a view, I want to get the `Combo` objects, but I want to sort them first by site name, then username.

I tried to create the view, but get errors about what fields I can order by **Cannot resolve keyword 'Site' into field. Choices are: dead, id, password, siteID, siteID_id, timestamp, username**

```
def current(request):
    current = Combo.objects.filter(dead=False).order_by('Site__name','username')
    return render(request, 'passwords/current.html',{'current':current})
```

Since I'm not necissarily entering the sites into the database in alphabetical order, ordering by siteID wouldn't be useful.  Looking for some help to figure out how to return back the list of Combo objects ordered by the Site name object then the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order this by `siteID__name`:

```
def current(request):
    current = Combo.objects.filter(dead=False).order_by('siteID__name','username')
    return render(request, 'passwords/current.html',{'current':current})
```

since that is the name of the `ForeignKey`. But that being said, normally `ForeignKey`s are *not* given names that end with an `ID`, since Django already adds an `_id` suffix at the end for the database field.

Normally one uses:

```
class Combo(models.Model):
    # …
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

if you want to give the *database* column a different name, you can specify that with the [**`db_column=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column):

```
class Combo(models.Model):
    # …
    site = models.ForeignKey(
        Site,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        db_column='siteID'
    )
```

Comment: I feel like I tried it that way, but I must have mistyped or something.  I was able to get it working, thanks.